# How to parse "|" in examples in karate

Tags: karate

I am using scenario outline feature of Karate framework. I have examples as follows:

```
|report_type|rule_id|tag|
```

In this rule_id has value like `"A|B, C|D"`
How can I provide it so tha rule_id param can have value as `"A|B,C|D"`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the `\` character to escape:

`A\|B,C\|D`